# can not alert variable in html onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can not using html onclick to alert a varible 
here is my html ,which used php to echo

```
    <?php
    $blog_owner='jean'; 

    echo '<span onclick="
    var blog_owner='.$blog_owner.';
    alert(blog_owner);


    " class="comment_r_button">Reply</span>';
   ?>
```

I find out if I assign number to $blog_owner, It works

Comment: This issue doesn't seem to be reproducible: http://jsbin.com/cucud/2/edit Check the page source to ensure that the expected markup is being generated. Also, inline js is bad practice (like onclick in your html). Ideally, JavaScript should be in js files. JavaScript can communicate to php though ajax, or in my opinion the worst scenario - set a global object with values that need to be communicated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create var to alert it try this.

```
echo '<span onclick="alert(' . $blog_owner . ')" class="comment_r_button">Reply</span>';
```

Comment: It's not working, beside, I have to save the data to a varible for further use

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function showBlogOwner(){
      var blog_owner = 'jean';
      alert(blog_owner);
    }
  </script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span onclick="showBlogOwner()" class="comment_r_button">Reply</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this if you want to do this in the same way, you were doing:

```
<?php
$blog_owner='jean'; 

echo '<span onclick="
var blog_owner=\"'.$blog_owner.'\";
alert(blog_owner); " class="comment_r_button">Reply</span>';
```

?>

However, you can ignore the variable & can write it as:

```
<?php
$blog_owner='jean'; 

echo '<span onclick="alert(\"'.$blog_owner.'\"); " class="comment_r_button">Reply</span>';
?>
```

Comment: If you are using any string, you should wrap that inside quotes.